# Thermoelectric Thomson effect as generator

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

In thomson effect we need an electrical current and a temperature difference at the same time. So it is possible use Thomson effect to generate an electric current? That is, how I generete an electric current with thomson effect if I need an electric to provoque the thomson effect? Thomson effect seems promissing because I only utilize a single conductor, but the thomson effect explanation it is very confuse. Is there something I'm not understanding well? I thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

The Thomson effect is the generation/absorption of heat at every point in the material where both a current and a thermal gradient exist. It is due to the change of the Seebeck coefficient along the material as the temperature changes, i.e. it is related to the temperature dependence of the Seebeck coefficient. It does not create a current, it requires it in order to exist. What it can do though, is affect the power output and efficiency of a thermoelectric generator.

However, in some configurations, for example involving a single material that completes a loop and to which 2 different points are kept at a different temperature, the Thomson effect will create a net emf even though the Seebeck effect cancels out and doesn't produce a net emf. In that particular case, the Thomson effect create a current. However it is useless in practice, as the Thomson coefficient of any material is usually way smaller than its Seebeck coefficient.

There are some smarter ways to improve on the power output of TEGs.

Comment: But, if I have a temperature gradient and an electric current, what is the interest in Thomson effect? That is, why apply an electric current and a temperature gradient to generate an absorption/generation of heat? Isn't it a waste to apply a temperature gradient to generate another "temperature gradient"? Or when you refer to absorption/generation of heat you are talking about another heat concept other than a "temperature gradient"? @untreated_paramediensis_karnik

Comment: Yes, I am talking about a heat generation/absorption, this is not a temperature gradient. One is a heat that is generated at every single point in the volume (just like Joule heat), the other is a temperature difference along a material.

Comment: Regarding the Thomson effect, it is interesting for several reasons. When it comes to power generation though, it still pales in comparison to the commonly used Seebeck effect. What the Thomson effect does, is that it modifies the heat that enters the generator, and the heat that leaves it. This can either hinder or enhance the generated power, depending on several parameters (such as the sign of the Thomson coefficients of the materials used).

Comment: Imagine that I have a n-type homogeneous material and I heat on of the ends. The  heated end will have a lower charge carriers concentration than the cold side, and so, I created a charge flow. The point is, this generates a current flow, but what is the effect? That is, to be the Seebeck effect I need two materials, and in Thomson effect I need a current and temperature gradient to be able to say that it is the Thomson effect even if it is a homogeneous material. What effect should I call it?

Comment: You do not need 2 materials for the Seebeck effect, despite this misconception to be everywhere. Historically it has been observed with 2 materials, that is all.